# Find min and max values in Range

Tags: excel, formula

I need to prepare the student attendance sheet from zoom meeting data file. My data is something like this

| Name (Original Name) | roll no. | Join Time | Leave Time | Duration (Minutes) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 002-Haseebuddin Shakir | 002 | 22/01/2021 03:42:49 PM | 22/01/2021 03:46:34 PM | 4 |
| 002-Haseebuddin Shakir | 002 | 22/01/2021 03:50:49 PM | 22/01/2021 05:31:34 PM | 100 |
| 003_Abdul Wasay | 003 | 22/01/2021 03:53:51 PM | 22/01/2021 04:31:30 PM | 98 |
| 003_Abdul Wasay | 003 | 22/01/2021 04:35:51 PM | 22/01/2021 05:00:30 PM | 60 |
| 003_Abdul Wasay | 003 | 22/01/2021 05:01:51 PM | 22/01/2021 05:31:30 PM | 20 |
| 004_Ismail (04_Ismail) | 004 | 22/01/2021 03:47:44 PM | 22/01/2021 05:31:31 PM | 104 |
| 005 saud | 005 | 22/01/2021 03:51:07 PM | 22/01/2021 05:31:43 PM | 101 |
| 006-Akber (Akber-006) | 006 | 22/01/2021 03:41:12 PM | 22/01/2021 05:05:43 PM | 85 |

I need help to find the 1st joined time, last left time and total of minutes. for understanding purpose used random figures.

I have tried thru pivot table but getting date 1900 whenever I use min/max and even tried aggregate function but I am not that perfect using aggregate.

Looking for output

| Name | Roll no | Join time | Last leave time | total no. min's |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 002-Haseebuddin Shakir | 002 | 22/01/2021 03:42:49 PM | 22/01/2021 05:31:34 PM | 104 |
| 003_Abdul Wasay | 003 | 22/01/2021 03:53:51 PM | 22/01/2021 05:00:30 PM | 178 |

Comment: Hello Anil, I am new to this and looking for option to attach/copy my data or file

Comment: thanks a lot Anil  and here is the link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ooJXDgm0Mr5P0KgKPRThvZq1wXkIZAVh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ooJXDgm0Mr5P0KgKPRThvZq1wXkIZAVh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Tell me one more thing, which version of excel are you using. Will a powerpivot solution go?

Comment: I am using excel 2013.

Comment: see the answer proposed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a powerquery/powerpivot solution like this -

- remove auto filter
- select data
- `from table` on `get&transform` group on `Data` tab

it will look like this

[image]

- select `name` and `rollnum` both, rightclick `group-by`.  add aggregations like the screenshot

[image]

- close and load the data back (it will automatically load to a new sheet in same book)

[image]

**Note** I think you'll these aggregations for each of the day for each of the roll number.  It is therefore, advised that create a separate column of date before loading the data into powerquery window and thereafter groupby on `name` `rollnum` and `date` columns.

Comment: Hi Anil, the output exactly what I am looking for....you are great sir.....but unfortunately I cannot find in my excel  - "from table on get&transform group on Data tab".... it's OK. I will google it from where I should get those options visible.

Comment: [add](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/start-the-power-pivot-add-in-for-excel-a891a66d-36e3-43fc-81e8-fc4798f39ea8) powerpivot add-in if you haven't already before

Comment: Glad to have been of help.  Kindly upvote and accept the answer as usually desired on Stack Overflow.